# Open directories default app

Tags: nautilus, default-programs, update-alternatives

When I use any program that tries to open a directory it uses wrong applications; it currently uses non-explorer *visual-studio-code* and I have no idea why.

I tried to setup *Nautilus* as the main app, but I was not successful using *system-stettings defaults*, any method in [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/), or even using *update-alternatives*.

How can I change the default app to open directories. And if its possible using *update-alternatives*, which is the correct group?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I have learned that default applications is more complicated than what I knew. For context, it turned out I am using an AppImage in i3wm, and that the app uses xdg-open to launch apps.

For people facing the same problem as I did, some interesting readings are
[this blog on AppImages](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/why-i-have-a-problem-with-appimages-on-linux/) and the [Archlinux documentation on xdg-utils](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-utils)

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

> **Solution :**

---

Go in settings scroll all the way to the bottom, click on default applications and then change them..

---

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but there is no "directory explorer" default application. That is why I started looking at `update-alternatives` hoping for an option. Then I found out about xdg-open, etc. thank you in any case